# Mapping through an Array of Objects doesn't work in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, key, react-props

I want to insert a key identifier in a React App. Currently, my key is being populated by the `Object.name` property. That is not ideal, as it could be duplicated and then `React` would start complaining. The server doesn't return such a key.

So, I thought, I would map through that array and use the `index` in my `key` parameter. So, this is what I did:

```
const item = itemsList.map((item, index) => ({
  ...item,
  index
}));
```

And used it here in my component:

```
<TableWithSearch
  keyField="item.index"
  data={itemsList}
  columns={getItemsTableColumns()}
  search
>
```

I think this is straightforward enough to understand. But then my app crashes. With the error:

`Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`.

Obviously I am doing something wrong, but I am looking at it, for the past 1 hour and still can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you show the `TableWithSearch` component also?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here with the map function ? What is your final objective ?

Comment: I am trying to avoid console errors, in the future. To be clear, `keyField= "name"` works. But, what if a user has 2 items with the same name, which I had in my mock server by mistake. React is gonna complain. So, I am taking the array of objects and trying to dd an index to each one. And use that index instead of a name for the key identifier...

Comment: shouldn't it be `key={index}` ?

Comment: Yeah, although it is a reusable component so, it is way more broad in its logic...

Comment: There is not enough code or context in your question. It doesn't seems like you are rendering an array of `TableWithSearch`, and it isn't clear what you do render in `itemsList.map`. this question is lacking a [mcve]

Comment: You are using `const item = itemsList.map()` but then in your component you say `data={itemsList}`, so your map acomplishes nothing because you are still using the non mapped array

Comment: `data={itemsList}`, I am still passing them in my function, in order to keep them in my scope.... I am also passing them as props, so I can reuse them in the component... What that has to do with anything. I am creating a new array with map, that includes the index property...

Answer (score 0):

keyField="item.index" is incorrect. Your are passing it as a string which is why you are seeing that error. Each element is getting the same string value of "item.index"

It should be keyField={item.index}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a few hours of thinking about your comments and answers, and some experimenting, I found a solution.

For the sake of explaining a solution more thoroughly I will post my entire component:

```
export class ItemsList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    listItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { listItems } = this.props;
    listItems();
  }

  renderGroups() {
    const { itemsList, user } = this.props;
    const items = itemsList.map((item, index) => ({
      ...item,
      index
    }));
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {itemsList.length > 0 ? (
          <Fragment>
            <PageHeader>
              Groups
              <span>({itemsList.length})</span>
            </PageHeader>
            <div className="mb-2">
              <TableWithSearch
                keyField="index"
                data={items}
                columns={getItemsTableColumns()}
                search
              >
              </TableWithSearch>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        ) : (
            <div>no items</div>
          )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

My mistake was that I was passing it `ListGroups` as a data attribute, which in return made it quite impossible for the component to read the groups array and take the index of it `Ids van der Zee` was right in his comment.

For some reason, `JSX` syntax on the key attribute didn't work as you guys suggested. I haven't investigated this, but I will and comment below.

The above example works like a charm. If you know why JSX Syntax didn't work, please feel free to comment. Thanks for your help guys..